# Bootstrap 3.2 won't style Spring MVC form:form

Tags: css, spring, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

I have a simple Spring MVC 4.x (tiles) scenario. Where in response to a URI a form is displayed, however, Bootstrap styling is not kicking in:

JSP:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<br/><br/><br/>
<form:form modelAttribute="car" method="post">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="title">Make</label>
      <form:input path="make"/>         
   </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="isbn">Model (Long Label)</label>
   <form:input path="model"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="isbn">Color</label>
     <form:input path="color"/>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form:form>
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">       
     <div class="header">

     </div>
     <div id="main-content-container">
       <!-- main body -->



  <br/><br/><br/>
  <form id="car" action="/libms/carsx" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="title">Make</label>
      <input id="make" name="make" type="text" value=""/>         
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="isbn">Model (Long Label)</label>
      <input id="model" name="model" type="text" value=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="isbn">Color</label>
        <input id="color" name="color" type="text" value=""/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>
     <div class="footer">

     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
   </body>
```

Looks like this on screen:
[image]

I have verified if Spring's form:form is removed and `<form>` is used instead, the styling kicks in.

Comment: Can you show the links to the css and how they are imported? webjars? Also you are missing a css class attribute from your form

Answer (score 1):

You need to include jquery and bootstrap on your page. For example:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
```

You may also want to make of use some other bootstrap elements such as cssClass.

For example:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="car" method="post">
```

...can be changed to:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="car" cssClass="form-horizontal" method="post">
```

And:

```
<label for="title">Make</label>
```

...can be changed to:

```
<label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Make</label>
```

And:

```
<form:input path="make"/>
```

...can be changed to:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <form:input path="make" cssClass="form-control"/>
</div>
```

As you mention, the Spring form functionality also kicks in since you're including the Spring form taglib as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you Included Bootstrap in your jsp page Like

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Products</title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Products</h1>
            <p>Add products</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    ....
```

I can't see it in your page